# Where is my Imagemagick installed?

Tags: 12.04, paths, mediawiki

I tried to locate it with `locate imagemagick`
My result is this :

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/imagemagick
/usr/lib/mime/packages/imagemagick
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-common
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/README.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick/copyright
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-common/copyright
/usr/share/menu/imagemagick
/var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick-common_8%3a6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick_8%3a6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.postrm
```

So which is the path of imagemagick now :( ? I need it to link to it in my mediawiki extension. Any help is upvoted fast !

i gues it's this :

```
 /usr/lib/mime/packages/imagemagick
```

but how can I check, or how can I know that ?

Comment: Doesn't MediaWiki need path to specific binaries provided by ImageMagick, like `/usr/bin/convert`? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_third-party_tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding to this list of files: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/imagemagick/filelist

You should use this values.

```
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = /usr/bin/convert
$wgImageMagickIdentifyCommand = /usr/bin/identify
```

Comment: okay so command to use is just `convert`

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki's [own page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInstalling_third-party_tools) states that you need to specify paths to specific binaries, i.e.

```
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = '/usr/bin/convert'
```

etc.